# Coypu screenshot

Tags: selenium, nunit, screenshot, coypu

On the end of a Scenario, I want to take a picture if it has failed. The following code does not work:

```
[AfterScenario]
public void AfterScenario()
{
    if(ScenarioContext.Current.TestError != null)
    {
     WebBrowser.Driver.CaptureScreenShot(ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title);
    }
}
```

I think this may be due to the fact that I start my browser using Coypu (which has selenium wrapped). The driver does not have a 'captureScreenShot' method implemented. So my question is: how can i take a screenshot after a scenario, when i start up my browser using coypu?

The code for starting the browser is the following:

```
sessionConfiguration.Driver = typeof (SeleniumWebDriver);
sessionConfiguration.Browser = Drivers.Browser.Firefox;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, this is not implemented in Coypu right now. Reason being I have simply never needed to take a screenshot since so far, and no one's asked till now.

To access the native driver (WebDriver in your case) use `BrowserSession.Native` then you can use WebDriver's GetScreenshot method. This would end up looking something like this (disclaimer: not tested):

```
var driver = (ITakesScreenshot) coypuBrowserSession.Native;

var screenshot = driver.GetScreenshot();

screenshot.SaveAsFile("c://screenshot.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

[I've opened an issue](https://github.com/featurist/coypu/issues/30) for you on github to have this added to Coypu's BrowserWindow API

Comment: The ability to take a screenshot has now been [added to Coypu](https://github.com/featurist/coypu/issues/30)

Answer (score 0):

This is now natively available in Coypu. You can find the documentation here:

https://github.com/featurist/coypu#screenshots